# Name of Mathematical Operation

Tags: arrays

What's the name of the mathematical operation between N arrays generating  coordinates of dimension N whose elements are the elements of the arrays? for example, say N=2,[1,2]*[3,4]=[(1,2),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)]. What's the name of the operation *?

Comment: It’s known as the cartesian product.

Comment: I am reasonably certain it’s the cartesian product--https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Comment: Thx, you've been pretty helpful, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Cartesian Product :
A X B - All ordered pairs from set A to set B.
For N sets(arrays), it's n-fold cartesian product. Refer to this link :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Comment: Thx for the wiki link, you've been pretty helpful,moreover, are you aware of the implementation of n-fold Cartesian product in Matlab for a given N. I've tried meshgrid of N=2, i.e, meshgrid([1,2],[1,2]), the result is valid, yet is it probable to figure out a function who takes N as an input argument and returns the corresponding result?

Comment: I got the ans,haha, based on an example commad in Matlab;[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6] = ndgrid([-1 1]);
r=[x1(:),x2(:),x3(:),x4(:),x5(:),x6(:)];

Comment: @JDw I don't know Matlab, but you can surely figure out a function to get the required set. Assume that you have to find A X B X C, A has x elements, B has y elements, C has z elements.
Start iterating every element of B, and to an empty set S, add all tuples (b,c) such that b is in B and c is in C. You get y*z elements in set S.
Now you need to find out A X S, do it the same way you did B X C. You can similarly do for N sets. The total elements will be the product of elements of all sets.